# Datapower WTX output issue

Tags: ibm-datapower, wtx

I am doing WTX transformation in datapower in probe i can see output is generated properly, but when I check the output in the target queue it is populating with the input request and the WTX transformed output. can i get some cause why it may come like this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have some action that takes INPUT as its input context before your WTX binary transform. Otherwise it gets passed along to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I normally set the WTX Transform as explicit and then have the INPUT as Input to the Action and explicitly set the "real" Inputs to the context of the Input-card(s) on the map.